# How to make a thread repeat in Android

Tags: android

I try to implement a `thread` that runs next to the main thread, this thread is`executed in 20 seconds`, I need that after finishing the thread `again it executes again` in a continuous way.

With this code the thread is executed once, but how do I do it to run again?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.
.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
.
.
    treadTimer();
}

private void treadTimer(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=1; i<= 20; i++){
                UnSegundo();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tarea Larga Finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

private void UnSegundo(){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @override
    public void run() {
        doYourThing();
        handler.post(this, 20000);
    }
}

handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: `Logic` I have a error with your code, please can you tune it